# Can a critical point be a local maximum /local minimum?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

So i was looking through past exams, and i came upon this question :

***If the derivative does not exist at a point, then this critical point cannot be either a local maximum or a local minimum.***

I think it is false.

Take for example, the function of f=absolute value of x. There is x=0. x=0 i assume is a critical point of the function due to the fact that the derivative doesn't exist at x=0.Please corrrect me if im wrong. I also understood that at x=0, there is a local minimum of the function .

So according to my understanding, the question is false. A critical point , where the derivative doesn't exists, can indeed be a local maximum or minimum .

correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: A  *critical point* is by definition a point where the derivative exists and is zero. Hence $x=0$ is not a critical point of $x\mapsto |x|$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The question seems to imply that this isn't the definition used in OP's text/book. I have seen sources differentiating between _stationary_ ("derivative exists and is zero") and _critical_ ("stationary or derivative doesn't exist").

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: The definition varies. Some textbooks, in fact every calculus textbook I've taught from (mid 1980s to mid 2000s) includes points of non-differentiability as critical points.

Comment: My textbook too. It says that critical points are where the derivative of x is equal to 0 or is indeed undefined.+